# Difference between variable in and out constructor function

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using ES6 for creating React Class

```
class MyClass extends React.component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.var1 = this.props.myValue;
    }
    var2 = this.props.myValue;
}
```

As you see, both `var1` and `var2` can be called by using `this.varName`.

My question is what is the difference or it just 2 ways to define React class variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are these methods equivalent? Well, yes and no...

---

#### Using Babel?

If you are using the **Babel** compiler (which you are if you are using **JSX**), then yes, these methods are equivalent and you can use whichever you prefer.

Also, see this [**demo**](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=env%2Ces2015%2Ces2015-loose%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoFMAeAXNA7AJjAEppjBYB0wA9gLYAO1ueW0A3gLABQ0v0NuCFgBOAV3LVhACnrDq9CAEpOPPmoij6aabPlKA3NzVqsACwCWECgDcwwgIzQAvNDOWKuhRVrwAamBBRNENVXgBfIz5bYQAmZ1cLK08rH39A4O4woA). (thanks to [@garry-taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1145413/garry-taylor) for pointing that out).

---

#### Not using Babel?

If you are not using **Babel** you cannot declare `var2` the way you did (as it currently stands). It's only a proposal for [**ESNext**](https://github.com/esnext/esnext) which is not yet an official part of ECMAScript.

For reference have a look [**here**](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-public-fields/):

> Today ES classes are currently limited to declarative specification of methods, but declarative specification of fields is left to ad-hoc expando mutations on class instances in various places.
>
> This proposal aims to provide a declarative mechanism for specifying fields intended to be placed on classes. Such a mechanism is useful for both developers and tooling alike as it provides a place to specify the intended properties.

And also [**here**](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields):

> ```
> class Counter extends HTMLElement {
>   constructor() {
>     super();
>     this.x = 0;
>   }
> ```
>
> With the ESnext field declarations proposal, the above example can be written as
>
> ```
> class Counter extends HTMLElement {
>   x = 0;
>   constructor() {
>     super();
>   }
> ```

---

#### Summary

Even though you can do this in Babel/React, it may be best to follow ES standards and declare your variables within the constructor; at least for now.

But yes, in React these are equivalent, and eventually the two methods ***might*** become identical in ES as well, if the proposal goes through.

Comment: note, this is possible if you're using babel. It supports this if your using React. https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=env%2Ces2015%2Ces2015-loose%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoFMAeAXNA7AJjAEppjBYB0wA9gLYAO1ueW0A3gLABQ0v0NuCFgBOAV3LVhACnrDq9CAEpOPPmoij6aabPlKA3NzVqsACwCWECgDcwwgIzQAvNDOWKuhRVrwAamBBRNENVXgBfIz5bYQAmZ1cLK08rH39A4O4woA

Answer (score 2):

There is a movement at the moment to stop using the constructor method for setting state and local vars.

This is related to ES16 using scope/binding correctly.

```
class MyClass extends React.component {
   var1 = this.props.myValue;
   var2 = this.props.myValue;
   doSomething = () => { /* "this" will be the component */ }
}
```

This is better than

```
class MyClass extends React.component {
   constructor(props){
      this.var1 = this.props.myValue;
      this.var2 = this.props.myValue;
      this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this);
   }

   doSomething() {
       // do something
   }
}
```

Comment: so it just 2 ways to define variable and no difference?